# Linked List is only printing last element after adding a new node

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++ and would like to know why my program is only printing the last node of my input file after adding a new node. After adding the new node it only prints the last node and the node the user enters in.

I also need help with searching for the highest gpa of all the students entered and displaying which student that is as well as their gpa.

Here is the input file:

```
14
Breen_Jeremy
482929
3.5
Burgess_Patrick
492929
3.2
Catalan_Kristian
393923
2.5
Clark_Brenna
848292
4.0
Duda_Heather
292032
3.7
Freeland_Jesse
391939
4.0
Jarvis_Stephen
392939
2.5
Lemieux_Tyler
392934
3.5
OConnell_Kelly
103939
4.0
Osborne_John
193945
2.8
Richards_Daniel
494585
3.0
Swanbeck_James
693922
3.5
Tayek_Chandler
592022
3.0
Whippen_Andrew
199502
2.8
```

Here is my program:

```
 // This program does some basic functionalities of using a linked list

 #include<iostream>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<cstring>
 #include<fstream>
 using namespace std;

struct node
{
string name;
int student_ID;
 double gpa;
node * next;
};



int main()
{
// Variable definitions
node * first;               // Pointer to the first node in the list
node * last;                // Pointer to the last node in the list
char more_nodes = 'y';  // Control to know if the user wants to enter more
int numStudents;
double largest_GPA;
string best_student;
bool swap = true;
ifstream database;
void print(node * first);

database.open("class_list.txt");


database >> numStudents;

// Creates the first node
first = new node;           // Create the first node
first -> next = NULL;   // Point it to NULL (since it's the end)
last = first;               // Point last to it (since it's the end)

 for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)      
  {

  database >> first -> name;
  database >> first -> student_ID;
  database >> first -> gpa; 
  print(first);
  }//end for




// This loop adds one new node, loads data into it, and updates pointers   
  while (more_nodes == 'y')
   {
   last -> next = new node;         // Get a new node tacked onto the end of the list

cout << "Enter the name of the student" << endl;
cin >> last -> next -> name;
cout << "Enter the student ID" << endl;
cin >> last -> next -> student_ID;
cout << "Enter the GPA of the student" << endl;
cin >> last -> next -> gpa;
last -> next -> next = NULL;        // Point the new node to NULL
last = last -> next;        // Toggle last to point to this new node (since it's the new "last")


cout << "Do you have more students to enter? Enter y for yes or n for no" << endl;
cin >> more_nodes;

++numStudents;
print(first);
}//end while


node * temp;
temp = first;


while (temp -> next != NULL)
{
while(swap)
{
   swap = false;
      if (temp -> next -> gpa > temp-> gpa)
       {
        largest_GPA = temp -> gpa;
         temp -> gpa = temp -> next -> gpa;
         temp -> next -> gpa = largest_GPA;
         temp -> name = best_student;
         swap = true;
         }//end if
  }//end while
  temp = temp -> next;
 }//end while

 cout << "The best student is " << best_student <<endl;
 cout << "The largest GPA is " << largest_GPA <<endl;


  database.close();

  return 0;

 }//end main



 // Print out the linked list by having a temporary pointer scroll through the entire list

void print(node * first)
  {
    node * temp;                // Make a temporary (dummy) pointer
    temp = first;               // Point it to the first node in the list

    while(temp != NULL)     // Continue until temp reaches NULL (the end)
    {


    cout << temp -> name << endl;       
    cout << temp -> student_ID << endl;
    cout << temp -> gpa << endl;
    temp = temp -> next;                    // Move temp to the next node

      }//end while

   }//end function
```

Comment: This seems very suspicious:  ` for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)      
  {

  database >> first -> name;
  database >> first -> student_ID;
  database >> first -> gpa; 
  print(first);
  }//end for
`
I never see you create another node and add it to the list.

Comment: How would I go about adding it to the list? I thought I was doing that in the while (more_nodes == 'y') loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, the correct header for the `std::string` definition is:

```
#include <string>
```

These refer to the C string library in different ways:

```
#include<string.h> // In the global namespace.
#include<cstring>  // In the std namespace.
```

If the program compiles with your compiler it is due to the implementation of the `iostream` or `fstream` headers and shouldn't be relied on.  It didn't compile with mine.

Next, the loop loading records from a file is only creating and reusing one node.  Here's a way to correct that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
{
    node* temp = new node;
    database >> temp->name;
    database >> temp->student_ID;
    database >> temp->gpa;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(first == NULL)
    {
        first = last = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}//end for

print(first);
```

Lastly, to find the best GPA, track the node with the largest GPA:

```
node* temp = first;
node* best = first;
while(temp != NULL)
{
    if(temp->gpa > best->gpa)
    {
        best = temp;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
}//end while

cout << "The best student is " << best->name << endl;
cout << "The largest GPA is " << best->gpa << endl;
```

Some other things to think about:

- What if the file is empty or doesn't exist?
- What if the number of students in the file is `0`?
- How do you handle a tie for largest GPA? There is a three-way tie in the file.

The code as is won't handle these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm too long code for me, BUT, being new and working with pointers can lead to head scratching moments. If you have extra time, try Java first. You will have a much harder time screwing with the pointers (because you don't get access to them), and you can still build structures like the linked list.

Also I don't like your loop structure, Your loop is initial loop (i = 0), and then the rest of it (i >= 0), when it could be easier to have it all on a single while. I suggest something like this:

```
continueprocessing = false;
if( filehascontents ) continueprocessing = true;
while( continueprocessing )
{
    if( !filestillhascontents )
    {
        continueprocessing = false;
        continue;//or break; whatever your style
    }

    /*read contents for this loop*/

    /*validate contents to process are valid node data*/
    if( !valid node data ) continue;

    //if we are still here that means we got data, and its valid node data
    node *n = new node;
    /*also initialize n with the data*/

    //you integrate this into the single loop, to me that's better, up to you
    if( first == null )
    {
        first = n;
        last = n;
        continue;
    }

    //now we are done with the initial linking case, work the regular cases
    last->next = n;
    last = n;
}
```

Basically on the style I show you you assume the regular case, but start the loop checking special conditions and exit early if you hit them. That way your structure is (loop) (special conditions block) (regular case block) (endloop)

Anyway onto your very own code, your for loop, which is the while on mine (one that adds nodes), sets everything to first and keeps overwriting the data there, so that's why you only have one node, because you never add nodes.

As a nitpick you have a loop at the middle that uses "swap", but swap definition is all the way up there, move the initialization down with the code that actually uses it, easier to work with later.

Finally your swap function is wrong, and the only way to keep it that simple yet working would be to reinitialize temp to first everytime a swap happens so you do the search from the beginning again until you are sure the whole list is in order.

EDIT: I see, its not just wrong, its all sorts of wrong, not sure if you want to order your list or you are only looking for the max node, so as another nitpick, try to be overly descriptive on your names and try to be nitpicky about semantics so others and you later on have more ease reading the code, I'd go with renaming temp to maxgpastudent for example, or even result, if you are only looking for the max node because it will be your result.

Then do not use largestGPA as a temp variable for your swapping, it is largestGPA and it should only contain the largest GPA, if you need a temp variable, create one. Finally if you are trying to reorder, redo the function because your assignments are mixing everything, you are swapping gpas, but not swapping the student name, and you dont have to swap values, it's a linked list, swap the links.